# How do I change properties of text that's being imported via php

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to change the font size and color of text being imported from a cvs file how do I do this?  All my attempts have failed.

This is the HTML/PHP:

```
<div id='body'>

    <div id='weeeeeeweeeeeee'> 
        <?php
            echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";

            $f = fopen("woooopwooop.csv", "r");
            while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    foreach ($line as $cell) {
                            echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
                    }
                    echo "</tr>\n";
            }
            fclose($f);
            echo "\n</table></body></html>";
        ?>
    </div
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
body {
font-size:500px;
color:red;
background-position:center;
background-image: url(BearBack1.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.bodytext p {
    font-size:22px;
}

P.blocktext {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 6em
}

#weeeeeeweeeeeee{
    color:white;
    height:400px;
    width:500px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top:250px;
    margin-bottom:auto;
}
```

I'm able to change the text to red in the Body div but I cant seem to change its size.

Comment: Can you provide the rendered html? This would allow us to better help you. I also would not render `<html><body>` inside a `<div>`

Comment: ... because `.bodytext p`  has `font-size: 22px` and you probably use this class in your CSV output.

Comment: I don't like the id name, weeeeeeweeeeeee. Far too easy to make mistakes in the number of e's. It's cases like this that introduce errors, folks!

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you need a table for, but let's sort out the real errors first, like the `<html>` inside the `<div>`.

Comment: One guess would be that you're using Quirks mode, and tables don't inherit font sizes from their parents in quirks mode. In that case the solution would be to use standards mode, or to assign the style to the table. Or, you're trying to put the table in the p, which won't work. p's can't contain tables. But we can't really tell without seeing your generated HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make it look a little like this:

```
<div id='body'>
    Some Red text before the white one
    <div id='weeeeeeweeeeeee'> 
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Your Stuff</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Something like this actually (with the clossing bracket in the one before the last div closing tag):

```
<html>
<body>
<div id='body'>
    Some Red text before the white one
    <div id='weeeeeeweeeeeee'> 
        <?php
            echo "<table>\n\n";

            $f = fopen("woooopwooop.csv", "r");
            while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                            echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
                    }
                    echo "</tr>\n";
            }
            fclose($f);
            echo "\n</table>";
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<body>
<html>
```

The HTMML and BODY tags inside the DIV are just messed up,

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand your PHP code correctly, it's set to read and render a csv file as a table, so it should look something like this.

I'm also guessing here but this would assume that what you want to change is the font in the td tags so you should see I've added some css to the effect.

```css
#weeeeeeweeeeeee td {
  font-size: 500px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="weeeeeeweeeeeee">
    <html><body><table>
      <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
      </tr>
      </table></body></html>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Also, remove the body and html tags from your echo string because you don't need those there.